# Alignment issue in context menu

Tags: css

[image: Context Menu]

The tickmark should be aligned with the text.

Styles :

```
   {
content: '\2713';
display: inline-block;
color: #990000;
float:right;
vertical-align: middle;

/*padding: 0 6px 0 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 10px;*/
  }
```

How can I make the correct alignment ?

Comment: provide your html code ..

Comment: Please provide a Stack Snippet, a JSFiddle, or a CodePen providing a complete example with all the relevent code.

Comment: you ask a question and you put the answer  very good so why you ask a question

Answer (score 0):

Change the css like this :

```
content: '\2713';
display: inline-block;
color: #990000;
float:right;
position: relative;    
transform: translateY(-100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.double {
border-style: double;
background-color:#50a8d8;
width:30%;
height:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div class="double" style="padding:5px; color:white;" > Pan   <i class="fa fa-check pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:black"></i> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```